# How to define no of retries should attempt with hystrix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I am using spring boot application. In that I am trying to consume third party services. As part of this we are using Hystrix.

I just wanted to know about configuring the number of retries that should attempt with hystrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hystrix Itself has nothing to do with Retries - it provides the abstraction of hystrix command that can success or fail (maybe after a number of retries - but its the internal implementation of the command itself that You (the programmer) should provide.

So You can check out [Spring Retry library](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) to implement retry logic and then use Hystrix on top of that